# How can I change how ppx_yojson_conv represents variants?

Tags: json, parsing, ocaml

I'm trying to model write the elasticsearch DSL in ocaml types. frequently, there are things that are well modeled by variants where the tag is a singleton key in an object. For instance on [interval queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-intervals-query.html), we might have a **match**, a **prefix**, a **wildcard**, etc. The DSL represents these like this;

```
{"match": {...match params}}
{"wildcard": {...wildcard params}}
{"prefix": {...prefix params}}
```

Writing out the `yojson_of_x` functions by hand seems like a huge amount of boilerplate, so I'd like to derive them, but [ppx_yojson_conv](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_yojson_conv) says it represents variants like this;

```
["match", {...match_params}]
```

Is there a way to add some other annotation to get it to change its behavior? coming from rust world, [serde](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html) calls this the "externally tagged" representation, but I don't know if it's possible to configure `ppx_yojson_conv` in a similar way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the representation used by ppx_yojson_conv, but you can add a layer on top that does the conversion that you want:

```ml
let to_assoc: [> Yojson.Safe.t ] ->  Yojson.Safe.t as 'a  = function
  | `List (`String key::l) -> `Assoc [key,`List l]
  | x -> x

let to_list = function
  | `Assoc [key,`List l] -> `List (`String key::l)
  | x -> x
```

Then you can transform `yojson` converters to your own with:

```
type t =
  | A of int
  | B of int
[@@deriving yojson]
let yojson_of_t x = to_assoc (yojson_of_t x)
let t_of_yojson x = t_of_yojson (to_list x)
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me that I could reference the derived definition of `yojson_of_t` in my implementation of `yojson_of_t`, but that's very helpful.